# Google Chrome hanging also causing the Windows 11 taskbar to hang

Tags: google-chrome, taskbar, windows-11

I have now twice experienced a situation where Google Chrome hangs, but the Windows 11 taskbar *also* hangs at the same time, so I can't close Google Chrome or open any other applications (except Task Manager - see below).

In the first case when this happened, I had another application running (Serial Debug Assistant). Closing that application somehow solved the problem. But in this case, there is no other application running, so I can't use that workaround.

While I am able to use Ctrl+Alt+Del to run Task Manager, I don't know what to do next.

I tried to terminate Windows Explorer, both by using Task Manager, and by using `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` from a cmd window that I launched from Task Manager, but neither of these methods worked.

Comment: I assume restarting File Explorer does not resolve the issue?  I experienced a similar situation, turned out to be a tab within a Chrouimium based browser, causing sever processor usage.

Comment: What exactly were you doing when this hang happened.

Comment: I had just resumed from sleep. I think that may have been the case both of those times.